# Show in which line crash has occur in flutter firebase crashlytics and also show dart file name

Tags: flutter, dart, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

[image]

In Flutter Firebase crashlytics report stack trace, it only shows "crash in dart file", not shows the dart file name, location and line where crash occur

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing a crash test using `FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();` you won't be able to see the crash line number.

For having a legit crash report you need to Crash the App programmatically.
Eg.

```
   bool isLegit = "true" as bool
```

This will cause a genuine crash and line number of the crash will be seen in reports with file name.